# Input.value becomes undefined when using ajax to refresh data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm updating data every 3 seconds but for some reason it is turning the input.value of both 'btc' and 'cur' to undefined. 
Here is the code to update the price

```
$(function() {
    getVars();
});
function getVars() {
$.getJSON('getPrice.php', function(data) { //getting vars from file
    currentPrice = data;
    var btc = document.getElementById("btc");
    var cur = document.getElementById("cur");
    if (currentInput == "btc") {
        btcConvert(accounting.unformat(btc.value));
    } else {
        usdConvert(accounting.unformat(cur.value));
    }
    });
    setTimeout("getVars()",3000);                //Refresh vars every 3 sec
            };
```

Here is the code for usdConvert and btcConvert

```
            var co2 = document.getElementById('btc');
            if (currentUnit == SAT) {
                var rounding = 0;                   
            } else if (currentUnit == BIT) {
                var rounding = 2;
            } else if (currentUnit == MBIT) {
                var rounding = 5;
            } else if(out2 == 0) {
                var rounding = 0;
            }else if(currentUnit == BTC) {
                var rounding = 8;
            }
            var trimmed = trim(accounting.unformat(accounting.formatNumber(out2, rounding)));
            btc.value = accounting.formatNumber(trimmed, decimalPlaces(trimmed));
        }

    If you inspect element you can see an error saying:
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. For some reason, the input.value is becoming undefined when I refresh the price.

Edit:
It might have something to do with how I set the initial btc.value in the html.

```
<center>
    <div class = "ratesBox">
    <div class = "bitcoin">
        <div class = "rateboxy"><input value = "1" type="text" name = "btc" id="btc" class="rate" onchange="btcConvert(this);" onkeyup ="btcConvert(this);"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class= "unitBox">
        <div class = "smallUnitBox" onclick="satoshiConvert(btc);" id="satoshiBox">sat</div>
        <div class = "smallUnitBox" onclick="bitConvert(btc);" id="bitBox">bit</div>
        <div class = "smallUnitBox" onclick="mBTCConvert(btc);" id="mBTCBox">mBTC</div>
        <div class = "smallUnitBox2" onclick="bitcoinConversion(btc);" id="BTCBox">BTC</div>
    </div>
            <p id = "equals">=</p>
        <div class = "rateboxy"><input value = "$<?php echo json_encode($bitcoinPrice); ?>" type="text" name="cur" id="cur" class="rate" onchange="usdConvert(this);" onkeyup ="usdConvert(this);"/></div>
    </div>
</center>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Oh my, `length` occurs like ten times in that code, and we have no idea where it's `undefined`? You couldn't narrow it down a bit, or at least point us to the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: Also, you're calling the function with `accounting.unformat(btc.value)` as an argument, and then you use that argument as a HTML input in the function, but does `accounting.unformat(btc.value)` somehow return an element then ?

Comment: My fault, it happens in btcConvert on this line: if(input.value.length > 17). If you go to satoshindex.com you can inspect element to check it out.

Comment: accounting.unformat uses http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/ and returns the number unformatted(without currency symbols/commas etc.)

Comment: `input.value` is undefined, probably because `input` isn't what you think it is. `input` is passed into the function as an argument from wherever you're calling it, and in the html you pass in `btc` whatever that is supposed to be, but lets assume it translates to `window.btc` and you get the element with that ID (bad way of doing things), but when you call it from your code you pass in `accounting.unformat(btc.value)`, which apparently returns numbers, and why would those numbers have a `value` property, or be like input elements ?

Comment: btc.value is the value inside of the top input box is it not?

Comment: @Darkstar in your btcConvert() function, `input.value` is the value inside the top input box, as I can see. At least when you change its value, you are calling that function with `this` as parameter, which in such function takes the `input` var name.

Comment: The lines that are causing the error are if (currentInput == "btc") {
             btcConvert(accounting.unformat(btc.value));
            } else {
             usdConvert(accounting.unformat(cur.value));
            }. All I'm trying to accomplish is updating the value inside the input box with the new price.

Comment: Lets start at the top, you call the function as `btcConvert(accounting.unformat(btc.value));`, where `btc` is an element, and the value returned from the `unformat` function is a number etc. You pass in that number to the function as `input` here `function btcConvert(input) {`, where input is the number you just sent to the function. Then you do `input.value`, but `input` is already the value, it's even *"unformatted"*, so you can't get the value again ?

Comment: I see what you're saying now.

Comment: Do you understand what I'm trying to accomplish though? Update the current values in the input boxes with the new price data.

Comment: If I reset currentPrice every x seconds and call the convert functions again shouldn't the input boxes reconvert with the new price data?

Comment: It should, but like @adeneo said, you'll have to call `btcConvert(accounting.unformat(btc));` (or `cur`) instead (without `.value`) because you're asking for `.value` again in the function.

Comment: This won't bother other function calls because they do it with the element only, without `.value`. So @adeneo made a really good point there, and I think it's the real issue.

Comment: That works! Thanks guys.

Comment: @adeneo post the answer so you get the points!